# handle exception pl/sql : get value where exception occured

Tags: oracle, plsql

I'm using this code

```
BEGIN
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'INSERT INTO MY_TABLE (A, B , C)
                  SELECT TABLE_2.A, TABLE_2.B, TABLE_2.C
                  FROM TABLE_2
                  WHERE TABLE_2.A in (val1,val2,val3) ';

EXCEPTION WHEN OTHERS then 
                PROC_EXCEPTION('ERROR',TABLE_2.B,SQLCODE,SQLERRM);
END;
```

And I'm getting the following compilation error:

> `TABLE_2.B must be declared`

how can I get the value of `TABLE_2.B` where the exception occurred and pass it to the procedure handling the exception?

Comment: You can't.  The exception is processed for the entire *statement*, not for the row that fails.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use clause  `LOG ERRORS INTO` https://oracle-base.com/articles/10g/dml-error-logging-10gr2

To create error log table please use https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14258/d_errlog.htm#CEGBBABI

Then after insert finishes you can process records from error table.

Comment: That will not catch syntax errors as the one shown in the question

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name yes this catches only some of exceptions in value not in syntax but the question was: how can I get value where error occured? So I understand it is about value inserted.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot reference `TABLE.A` outside the `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE` block...

Try:

```
BEGIN
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'INSERT INTO MY_TABLE (A, B , C)
              SELECT TABLE_2.A, TABLE_2.B, TABLE_2.C
              FROM TABLE_2
              WHERE TABLE_2.A in (val1,val2,val3) ';

EXCEPTION WHEN OTHERS then 
            PROC_EXCEPTION('ERROR with TABLE_2.B',SQLCODE,SQLERRM);
END;
```

To have value for `TABLE_2.B` do it in a loop:

```
BEGIN
  for x in (SELECT TABLE_2.A, TABLE_2.B, TABLE_2.C
              FROM TABLE_2
              WHERE TABLE_2.A in (val1,val2,val3))
  loop
    begin
      execute immediate 'INSERT INTO MY_TABLE (A, B , C) values ('||x.A||','||x.B||','||x.C||')';
        EXCEPTION WHEN OTHERS then 
           PROC_EXCEPTION('ERROR with'|| x.B,SQLCODE,SQLERRM);
    end;
  end loop;

END;
```

Comment: thanks for the answer .. but what if I actually had case when then in my select statement how can I use in insert values ?